# Custom View Controller Transition with Parameter

Tags: ios, user-interface

I'm implementing a custom Transition Controller designed to make it look like the new view expands from part of the old view.  This isn't difficult to accomplish, but I have multiple places that I want the "origin" point to be.

Is there any way to pass a "parameter" to the Transition Controller from the view that is using the custom transition?  In this case, I would pass a frame variable.  Or do I have to create 9 different Transition Controllers with almost exactly the same code?

Comment: Refer this url : http://blog.dadabeatnik.com/2013/10/13/custom-segues/

Comment: This also looks like it would have worked, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this in the delegate's method where you return your custom animation controller. For example you can implement a custom init method:

```
    - (id <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animationControllerForPresentedController:(UIViewController *)presented
                                                                       presentingController:(UIViewController *)presenting
                                                                           sourceController:(UIViewController *)source {
        CGRect someFrame = CGRectMake(....);
        return [MyCustomAnimationController alloc] initWithStartFrame:someFrame];
    }
```